# An idiom for "tangential association"

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom to replace 'tangential association'in this sentence ?

> " She pictured this man, Jared, with the woman, Lisa, but failed to connect the two in any way but tangential association. "

Not really, what I'm looking for is the phrase that describes connecting two things without any 'normal' or objective, clear association

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase you may be looking for is

> by association

which means there is an unspecified connection between two things, as in

> He was guilty *by association*.

meaning he was guilty due to some *unspecified involvement* with whatever happened.

So, your sentence might be reworded as

> She thought Jared was involved with Lisa *by association*.

meaning she thought they were in a relationship because they were together.